# How to customize expireAfterWrite for concrete cache if I use cacheBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, caching, caffeine-cache

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571018/2674303) I try to use customized `expireAfterWrite` for "customCache"

So my config look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CaffeineCacheConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager(Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineCacheBuilder) {
        CaffeineCacheManager result = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        result.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineCacheBuilder() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(10000)
                .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .recordStats();
    }

    @Bean
    public CaffeineCache customCache() {
        return new CaffeineCache("customCache",
                Caffeine.newBuilder()
                        .maximumSize(10000)
                        .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .recordStats()
                        .build());
    }
}
```

Then in codeBase I use:

"customCache"

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("customCache")
String result = cache.get("myKey", () -> "cachedValue")
```

And based on my experiments it keeps values on cache pnly 60 seconds by I expect 60 minutes.

How to achieve desired result ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Spring. I believe you can use [registerCustomCache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/caffeine/CaffeineCacheManager.html#registerCustomCache-java.lang.String-com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache-) for this scenario.

Comment: @Ben Manes hm... spring 5.1.19 doen't have such method

Comment: it is available since 5.2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way to do this is as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CaffeineCacheConfig
{
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(
            @Qualifier("oneMinuteCache") final Cache<Object, Object> oneMinuteCache,
            @Qualifier("oneHourCache") final Cache<Object, Object> oneHourCache)
    {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
                new CaffeineCache("oneMinuteCache", oneMinuteCache),
                new CaffeineCache("oneHourCache", oneHourCache)));
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public Cache<Object, Object> oneMinuteCache()
    {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(10000)
                .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .recordStats()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Cache<Object, Object> oneHourCache()
    {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(10000)
                .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .recordStats()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: will SimpleCacheManager work together with CaffeineCache ?

Comment: My answer does use those two together. Unless you mean something else, yes. My code is a *working* example.

Comment: @Bean over 
oneMinuteCache() and oneHourCache() looks redundant you can direcrly call the method