# caffeine Cache is not evicted after expireAfterAccess/expireAfterWrite

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache, caffeine-cache

**My configuration:**

```
@Bean
public CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new CaffeineCacheManager();
}

@Bean
public CaffeineCache testCache() {
    return new CaffeineCache("test_cache",
            Caffeine.newBuilder()
                    .maximumSize(10000)
                    .expireAfterAccess(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .recordStats()
                    .build());
}
```

**test code:**(read cache 3 times in a row with 45 seconds pause between reads)

```
static int value = 1;
    ...

    Cache testCache = cacheManager.getCache("test_cache");
    System.out.println("read " + testCache.get("myKey", () -> value++));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(45000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("read " + testCache.get("myKey", () -> value++));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(45000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("read " + testCache.get("myKey", () -> value++));
```

**Actual result:**

```
read 1
read 1
read 1
```

**Expected result:** Cache is evicted after 30 seconds:

```
read 1
read 2
read 3
```

What do I wrong ?

How to fix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fyi, `CaffeineCacheManager` and `CaffeineCache` are Spring wrappers around the real Caffeine cache.

**`org.springframework.cache.caffeine`**.`CaffeineCache` implements **`org.springframework.cache`**.`Cache` (emphasis on packages of both)

As to your question, `CaffeineCacheManager` returned from your `@Bean` has **NO** caches actually. So when you call `cacheManager.getCache("test_cache")`, you get a cache created by Spring on the fly, called a dynamic cache. And this cache's `expireAfterAccess` and `expireAfterWrite` are not set. Hence, the `1` you put in it is never evicted.

To get expected behavior, you need to add `CaffeineCache` to the cache manager. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68535564/818006).